# How to fix - "ValueError: Input arrays should have the same number of samples as target arrays. Found 8 input samples and 33984 target samples."

Tags: python, deep-learning, lstm, recurrent-neural-network

I'm trying to fit RNN model on top of my data but it shows an input error : ValueError: Input arrays should have the same number of samples as target arrays. Found 8 input samples and 33984 target samples.

Attaching screenshot for reference.

https://drive.google.com/open?id=1UjO7yQjD2_52PhTLYAYoZGfQsl1bboSW

https://drive.google.com/open?id=13k2sUvEVYoJGV7bR_dxh25C-sC8Tva0L

```
def RNN():
inputs = Input(name='inputs',shape=[max_len])
layer = Embedding(max_words,50,input_length=max_len)(inputs)
layer = LSTM(64)(layer)
layer = Dense(256,name='FC1')(layer)
layer = Activation('relu')(layer)
layer = Dropout(0.5)(layer)
layer = Dense(1,name='out_layer')(layer)
layer = Activation('sigmoid')(layer)
model = Model(inputs=inputs,outputs=layer)
return model


model = RNN()
model.summary()

model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy',optimizer=RMSprop(),metrics=['accuracy'])


model.fit(sequences_matrix,y_train,batch_size=128,epochs=10,
      validation_split=0.2,callbacks=  [EarlyStopping(monitor='val_loss',min_delta=0.0001)])
```

The shape of my data that i'm trying to fit into the run model:

```
X_train.shape = (33984, 8)
y_train.shape = (33984,)
X_test.shape =  (14565, 8)
y_test.shape = (14565,)
```

Comment: You are not passing x_train to model.fit, seems to be just a typo, passing the wrong data.

Comment: Thanks Matias! But after passing X_train to model.fit i am still getting this errorValueError: Error when checking target: expected activation_2 to have shape (1,) but got array with shape (8,)